# Can rpm upgrades and rpm erases be mixed in the same command (transaction)

Tags: linux, rpm, package-management

I would like to upgrade package A and at the same time erase package B.

There are dependencies between the packages so I would like to do both operations as one transaction.

This can be done with 2 commands:

rpm --erase packageB.rpm
rpm -Uvh packageA.rpm

Can it be done as one command?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with the `rpm` command on the command line, but you can do it with `yum shell`:

```
# yum shell
Setting up Yum Shell
> install package1
> erase package2
> run
```